# Spring boot domain class required for mapping table

Tags: spring-boot, grails-domain-class

I m new to Spring Boot. I have a table (Team) that has resources, am storing in a separate table (Resources) and have team_resource mapping table (with fields teamid, resourceid). My question is should I have a domain class for the mapping_table too ?

When I m inserting a new team (POST) with resources I create entry in all 3 tables. I m using facade/dao pattern for writing/ reading to the DB. I have to handle when the team is modified/ deleted. Should I have a domain class for the mapping_table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple approaches you can handle it

**Approach 1**

Define `@ManyToMany` between your Team and Resources entity like this:

1. In Team Entity

   ```
   @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
       cascade = {
           CascadeType.PERSIST,
           CascadeType.MERGE
       })
   @JoinTable(name = "resources",
       joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "id") },
       inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "id") })
   private Set<Resources> resources= new HashSet<>();
   ```
2. In your resources entity:

   ```
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
           cascade = {
               CascadeType.PERSIST,
               CascadeType.MERGE
           },
           mappedBy = "resources")
   private Set<Team> teams= new HashSet<>();
   ```

**Approach 2**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "team_resources")
public class TeamResources implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private TeamResourcesId id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "team_id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Team team;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "resources_id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Resources resources;

    public TeamResources (Team u, Resources r) {
        // create primary key
        this.id = new TeamResourcesId (u.getUserId(), q.getQuestionId());

        // initialize attributes
        this.user = u;
        this.question = q;
    }

    @Embeddable
    public static class TeamResourcesId implements Serializable {

        @Column(name = "team_id")
        protected Long teamId;

        @Column(name = "resources_id")
        protected Long resourcesId;

        public TeamResourcesId () {

        }

        public TeamResourcesId (Long teamId, Long resourcesId) {
            this.teamId= teamId;
            this.resourcesId= resourcesId;
        }
  //Getter , setter. equal and hash
}
```

so to answer your question, follow second approach and its good to not define bidirectional approach as it can lead to some run time problem if not handled properly.